# Error: Cannot find module 'AsyncDependencyToInitialChunkWarning'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I have succesfully installed and deployed to my Debian production server a react app using "create-react-app". I've then pushed it to my repo and pulled it on my development computer (Win10). Here's the output for `npm install && npm start`

```
C:\Users\Shad\shadfront>npm install
[       ...........] / extract:webpack-manifest-plugin: verb lock using C:\Users\Shad\AppDat
[       ...........] / extract:webpack-manifest-plugin: verb lock using C:\Users\Shad\AppDa
[       ...........] / extract:webpack-manifest-plugin: verb lock using C:\Users\Shad\AppD
[       ...........] / extract:webpack-manifest-plugin: verb lock using C:\Users\Shad\AppData[       ...........] / extract
:webpack-manifest-plugin: verb lock using C:\Users\Shad\A[       ...........] / extract:webpack-manifest-plugin: verb lock
using C:\Users\Shad\A[       .npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must ins
tall peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"}
(current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

added 755 packages in 21.316s

C:\Users\Shad\shadfront>npm start

> shadfront@0.1.0 start C:\Users\Shad\shadfront
> node scripts/start.js

module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './AsyncDependencyToInitialChunkWarning'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Shad\shadfront\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:23:46)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! shadfront@0.1.0 start: `node scripts/start.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the shadfront@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Shad\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-07-17T14_10_23_162Z-debug.log
```

What should I do in order to have my React app working on my Win10 ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone ending up here, I've managed to fix this problem by removing my .gitiginore and commiting again.